# Collada (.dae) meshes with unit != "meter" broken?

Tags: rviz, urdf, moveit, collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear community,

I'm having trouble with URDFs that used to work since Hydro.
If they contain a collada (.dae) mesh which has  with non meter units (e.g. centimeter):

```
--- collada_unit_meter.dae      2015-02-16 11:14:28.128423513 +0100
+++ collada_unit_centimeter.dae 2015-02-16 11:16:06.542388857 +0100
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@
     </contributor>
     <created>2015-02-16T11:14:28</created>
     <modified>2015-02-16T11:14:28</modified>
-    <unit name="meter" meter="1"/>
+    <unit name="centimeter" meter="0.01"/>
     <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
   </asset>
   <library_images/>
@@ -97,4 +97,4 @@
   <scene>
     <instance_visual_scene url="#Scene"/>
   </scene>
-</COLLADA>
\ No newline at end of file
+</COLLADA>
```

no mesh at all is displayed in rviz RobotModel.
It seems the mesh is also ignored for MoveIt! collision checking.

Test files can be created by simply exporting the default cube as .dae in Blender. Once without modification and once with modified . These files can also be found here:
https://gist.github.com/andreasBihlmaier/576b5bc3837c568a6730

Can anybody confirm this issue?

Regards,
ahb

**Addition**: The same meshes (with unit != meter) worked fine and *continue to work fine* with gazebo. Actually, I convert the .sdf to .urdf using pysdf.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203188/collada-(.dae)-meshes-with-unit-!=-%22meter%22-broken?/) by [andreasBihlmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/13776/andreasbihlmaier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2015-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like a regression to me, you should probably file a bug ticket for rviz. The fact that things ceased working also for moveit suggests a broader issue with how mesh loading works, however. Hopefully, a issue on rviz will trigger the necessary discussion of this.

While I can't confirm your issue directly, I also noticed changes in COLLADA handling between hydro and indigo. I encountered another issue where rendering didn't work in hydro, but did so in indigo (see [drcsim Bitbucket #466](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/466/collada-loading-errors-with-drcsim)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andreasBihlmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/13776/andreasbihlmaier/) on 2015-02-16**:
I was not sure where to file the bug (rviz, urdfdom, ...), thus I wanted to ask here before.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2015-02-23**:
I can confirm this issue. Meshes get loaded fine without any error message, but nothing is displayed. Re-exporting such that the unit is meter seems to be the only remedy. These are meshes that worked fine in rviz hydro.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2015-02-23**:
These test meshes do not work for me with current ros indigo from apt on ubuntu 14.04: https://github.com/garaemon/rviz_collada_marker

**Comment by [andreasBihlmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/13776/andreasbihlmaier/) on 2015-02-24**:
Against which repository should we fill a bug report?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2015-02-24**:
I guess https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-25**:
Yes, please open an issue on rviz, and include what version you are using and the example repository you have linked in the original question.

**Comment by [andreasBihlmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/13776/andreasbihlmaier/) on 2015-02-25**:
Done:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/853